# Абстрактный метод для сущности в spring data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa

Необходимо создать сущность, instance которой может иметь свой метод. Для этого был создан абстрактный класс сущности, с абстрактным методом.

Есть ли возможность сделать что-то такое?

Пример:
Есть сущность button с абстрактным методом

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buttons")
public abstract class Button {

    // ...

    public abstract void onClick(/* ... */);

    // ...

}
```

Нужно сохранить instance с указанным методом

```
Button button = new Button(/* ... */){
    @Override
    public void onClick(/* ... */) {
        // ...
    }
};

buttonService.save(button);
```

База данных MySQL.

Comment: 1. Абстрактные классы не могут быть сущностями. 2. Методы в базе не хранятся. 3. Учите что такое база данных. 4. Учите что такое JPA и Hibernate. Дурацкий вопрос!

Comment: @notaProgrammer на самом деле это не такой уж и глупый вопрос :)

Comment: @notaProgrammer спасибо, очень полезный совет, прям аж побежал учить что такое БД. В базе методы могут не храниться, но могут быть названия методов. Ответ на свой вопрос я уже нашел.

В python методы могут быть сущностями. Мне вот это было необходимо. В одном из предыдущих проектов я мог хранить метод как сущность в NoSQL БД. Теперь, мне необходимо реализовать что-то похожее в MySQL БД

Comment: В Java методы не могут быть сущностями. Вы не понимаете концепций JPA / Hibernate, я как раз на это и указывал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опишите задачу подробнее.

Если необходимо сохранить информацию о классе вместе с данными это можно сделать, однако это сложный сценарий.

Вам необходимо сериализовать .class файл каким либо образом и сохранить его. А при считывании десериализовать его, загрузить classloader'ом и потом уже создавать его инстансы.

Например apache hadoop, он отправляет задание на ноды в виде jar, который содержит код, оперирующий над данными, которые хранятся на этих нодах.

Comment: боюсь автор вообще ничего не понял

Answer (score 1):

Есть некая альтернатива хранению методов. Такой способ потребует пересборки проекта, но для моей задачи этого достаточно.

Можно хранить в БД название статического метода и вызывать его таким образом.

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;

try {
    method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
}catch(/* ... */){
    /* ... */
}
```

Разумеется, такое применение не безопасно, но других альтернатив, кроме указанной @StrangerintheQ, я не вижу

Comment: да, то что описывал я это несколько иное, у вас получается так что не нужно хранить ни метод ни класс, достаточно имени, я же лписал как сохранить код в бд, например для передачи другой программе данных вместе с классом, о котором она не знала при запуске

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Верно. И ответ у вас верный. Спасибо, но на самом деле, БД получится слишком громоздкой при большом объеме сериализированных методов и классов. Но так, ответ правильный.

Answer (score 0):

JPA может сохранить только данные из полей класса.
Методы хранить в БД не получится.
Скорее всего вам придётся писать отдельные классы, наследующие абстрактный класс Button, и на них уже мапить данные из БД.